# Express React cookie issues

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, cookies, passport.js

So here I am building an application based on NodeJS with express4 as the backend and a React frontend. The backend currently allows a user to log in and create an event. This functionality was tested using Postman and works just fine.

Now in the frontend my backend tells me I am unauthorized. Funnily enough when I use a chrome extension to replace the stored cookie (in the browser for the frontend) by the cookie from Postman it suddenly works. So somehow something with cookies must be going wrong.

```
//Session used in express
app.use(session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  store: new MongoStore({
    url: process.env.MONGODB_URI || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI,
    autoReconnect: true
  }),
  name: 'UsE'
}))
```

The frontend then uses a [fetch polyfill](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) to make the login request.

```
export const loginAction = (email, password) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(startLoginFetching())
    return fetch(baseURL + '/api/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email,
                password
            })

    }).then(response => {
        if(response.ok) {
            dispatch(loginUser())
            dispatch(push('/home'))
        }

        //Read the JSON stream and return it's promise.
        return response.json()
    }).then(json => {
        if(json.msg) {
            dispatch(displayToast(json.msg))
        }
        if(json.user) {
            dispatch(updateUser(json.user))
        }
        dispatch(endLoginFetching())

    })
  }
}
```

Then the backend uses pasport to authenticate the user and everything should be fine. I am totally at a loss as to what could be the issue here.

Here is the code making a request to the backend that gets a 401 back.

```
export const createEvent = (infos) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(startFetching('createEvent'))
  return fetch(baseURL +'/api/event', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify(infos)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        if (json.msg) {
            dispatch(displayToast(json.msg))
        }
        if(json.event) {
            dispatch(addEvent(json.event))
            dispatch(push(`/event/${json.event._id}`))
        }
        dispatch(endFetching('createEvent'))
    })
}
```

Comment: Do you really need a `Mongo DB` for maintaining sessions?

Comment: Hi, 
Take a look at this, it might help - https://medium.com/@ar7casper/authentication-using-express-js-passport-js-7ae7a7484a55#.u6b9lpdeb

Comment: @PraneshRavi it is needed according tot he documentation because otherwise you will get memory problems with sessions leaking out.

Comment: @alexunder nice read, but sadly nothing helpfull. Though now I am sure that I don't need the cookie-parser package.

Comment: @H_end-rik did you ever find a solution? I'm also having the same issue as you!

Comment: @ezg I think I did but sadly can't recall and don't have access to the codebase anymore. Sorry to disappoint.

Answer (score 1):

By default the `fetch` polyfill [does not pass along cookies to the server](https://github.com/github/fetch#caveats). To [send cookies](https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies) with requests made to the same origin, you need to include `credentials: 'same-origin'` in the options you're passing to `fetch()`.

Your updated code should look like this:

```
fetch(baseURL + '/api/login', {
          method: 'POST',
          credentials: 'same-origin',
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              email,
              password
          })

}).then(response => { // ...
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the reply. This would be awesome but I am currently using CORS and have the `credentials` field set to "include" as per the documentation for CORS.